# sonarqube failed to start

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-14.04, sonarqube5.6

I am currently trying to install sonarqube to try it, but I am unable to make it start.
My OS is Ubuntu 64 bits.

What I did :

First I wanted to try it with all basics settings so I downloaded the last version of sonarqube on their website (5.6). Then I unzipped it and went to the bin/linux-x86-64/ and then I did ./sonar.sh start

The terminal then said Sonarqube started. However, I can't get access to it on the web interface, and my logfile is fulled with this error.

> 2016.06.20 15:33:15 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.RubyRailsContextListener
>
> org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]

Full log on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nNmquxGQ)

I am searching a lot since this morning to find out how to solve this but I did not find the answer at this time. Have you any idea or solution to solve this ?

#### EDIT :

Tried it on my Windows 7 OS => No problem at all, it works perfectly without editing anything. Maybe something is not installed on my Ubuntu sessions, I do not know. I still did not find the fix at the moment.

#### EDIT 2:

I tried ./sonar.sh console (can't edit my first message because it would be too long)

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:43:46 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/temp
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:43:46 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process3660637613352616230properties
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:43:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:43:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /home/chris/Téléchargements/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process3224593936857414396properties
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:44:19 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2016.06.21 08:44:20 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I tested on an other computer running Ubuntu 64 bits, with an other connection : exact same error. I do not know what to do at this point ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fixed my problem. My sonarqube folder was in a directory containing "é" in his name. It seems that it caused some issues. I moved my folder on my Desktop and tried again, and it works